# sqldeveloper on hidpi linux

Tags: linux, oracle-sqldeveloper, hidpi

I have sqldeveloper 18.2 installation on hidpi machine (xps 9370 with 4k display) and it's unusable due to scaling issues.

I have tried to launch it using different options:

1. As is - interface icons and fonts too small
2. As is increasing interface font - text overlapping makes it unusable
3. Using gdk_scale with Java9
4. Using -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2 with Java8

It seems points 3 and 4 do scaling but with glitches making it unusable again.

[Glitch example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfN3O.png)

I'd like to stick with 4k resolution as it really has difference vs fullhd

I will appreciate if you can direct me where to dig or resolve the issue at all

Thank you!

Comment: Try oracle Java 8 JDK

Comment: Tried it as described in p4. Same glitches.

Comment: as a workaround, on next startup, go to the Welcome Page, scroll down to the bottom, and uncheck, open on startup. then restart SQLDev. Also see if your OS (Windows supports this) has an option to disable scaling for specific applications.

Comment: There is no checkbox to disable welcome page on startup) It seems another glitch

Comment: Let me know if the below answer doesn't work I think I have a separate answer

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli, thanks. The solution below works flawlessly.

Answer (score 12):

Append to `/opt/oracle-sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf` the following: `AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2` and it should work.

Comment: This works great, and does  exactly what we need. But it only works in sqldeveloper 19, so if you are using an earlier version you will need to upgrade first.

Comment: Only problem is that while 1.0 is tiny, 2.0 scaling is HUGE and floats don't seem to work. also tried `-Dsun.java2d.win.uiScaleX=125% -Dsun.java2d.win.uiScaleY=125%` and `1.25` and such for the values and none of them work.

Comment: Have you tried enabling/disabling `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=true/false`? Also according to [this](https://news.kynosarges.org/2019/03/24/swing-high-dpi-properties/) you can use float values as a parameters for uiScale

Answer (score -1):

I've found solution! Just set -Dsun.java2d.xrender=true and sqldeveloper launched with almost no glitches.

File: {install_dir}/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf

There is some interesting point. "Show on startup" checkbox on welcome page is accessible while -Dsun.java2d.opengl is set to true. But this option leads to major ui drawing glitches

Comment: Didn't work for me either (on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS).  I finally reduced my screen resolution to HD.